# Python code for finding reverse average (finding possible value sets that give a certain average)

Tags: python, average

Background: I am working in Python 3, but if people provide answers in other programming languages I can still use it.  Any suggestions on functions or efficient algorithm or programming tips would be helpful.

Problem:  I have a problem involving sets of four (4) integers and their average values.

The information given:
1. the number of integers in the set (4)
2. the average of the integers

The information needed:
1. list of possible values that would result in the given average

Notes: The number of integers in the set is small so an efficient method of generating lists shouldn't be that hard, but so far I am stuck.  I have been starting with the sum of the numbers (average * 4), but haven't found the right way to iterate yet.

EDIT:
All integers are non-negative.  For my purposes they also aren't bigger than 8 digits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I will add my code to the question.

Comment: There have to be some constraints implied, e.g. all integers should be positive. Otherwise, there are an infinite number of possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the sum, N, rather than the average.

```
def all_possibilities(N, k=4):
    if k == 1:
        yield (N,)
        return
    for i in xrange(N+1):
        for p in all_possibilities(N-i, k-1):
            yield (i,) + p


print list(all_possibilities(5))
```

Produces:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 5), (0, 0, 1, 4), (0, 0, 2, 3), (0, 0, 3, 2), (0, 0, 4, 1),
 (0, 0, 5, 0), (0, 1, 0, 4), (0, 1, 1, 3), (0, 1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 3, 1),
 (0, 1, 4, 0), (0, 2, 0, 3), (0, 2, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2, 1), (0, 2, 3, 0),
 (0, 3, 0, 2), (0, 3, 1, 1), (0, 3, 2, 0), (0, 4, 0, 1), (0, 4, 1, 0),
 (0, 5, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 4), (1, 0, 1, 3), (1, 0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 3, 1),
 (1, 0, 4, 0), (1, 1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 3, 0),
 (1, 2, 0, 2), (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2, 0), (1, 3, 0, 1), (1, 3, 1, 0),
 (1, 4, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0, 3), (2, 0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 2, 1), (2, 0, 3, 0),
 (2, 1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2, 0), (2, 2, 0, 1), (2, 2, 1, 0),
 (2, 3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0, 2), (3, 0, 1, 1), (3, 0, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0, 1),
 (3, 1, 1, 0), (3, 2, 0, 0), (4, 0, 0, 1), (4, 0, 1, 0), (4, 1, 0, 0),
 (5, 0, 0, 0)]
```

In general, there will be choose(N+k-1, k-1) solutions.

A shorter solution leveraging `itertools.combinations` is this:

```
import itertools

def all_possibilities(N, k=4):
    for c in itertools.combinations(range(N + k - 1), k - 1):
        yield tuple(x - y - 1 for x, y in zip(c + (N + k - 1,), (-1,) + c))
```

Comment: since the question talks about a *set* of integers I would assume they have to be unique. But the question should probably clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are really looking for a *set* of (unique) non-negative integers, you can name the integers `a, b, c, d` such that `a > b > c > d` and note that they have to sum to `average * 4`. Then you can find the combinations with a generator function like this:

```
def get_4set_with_average(average):
    target_float = average * 4.0
    target = int(target_float)
    if target_float != target or target < 6:
        raise ValueError('No combinations possible')
    for a in xrange(target):
        for b in xrange(a):
            for c in xrange(b):
                for d in xrange(c):
                    if a + b + c + d == target:
                        yield([a, b, c, d])

print list(get_4set_with_average(4))
```

This can be made more efficient in various ways by taking into account the relationships between the four integers...

```
given that...
    a > b > c > d >= 0 and a + b + c + d = target 
it must be that...
    3 <= a <= target - 3,
    2 <= b <= target - a - 1,
    (target - a - b) / 2 < c <= target - a - b
```

This gives us:

```
def get_4set_with_average(average):
    target_float = average * 4.0
    target = int(target_float)
    if target_float != target or target < 6:
        raise ValueError('No combinations possible')
    for a in xrange(3, target - 2):
        for b in xrange(1, min(a, target - a)):
            for c in xrange(int((target - a - b) / 2) + 1, 
                            min(b, target - a - b + 1)): 
                yield([a, b, c, target - a - b - c])
```

(I've tested this a bit, but not thoroughly - you will need to check it.)

No doubt there are more efficient algorithms, but the sheer number of possible combinations makes this difficult to run for large values. (Even average = 20 takes a long time on my machine.)